# append the data to android webview at run time

Tags: android, webview

i am displaying a webpage in the webview . im adding some more content to webview at run time as  follows

`webContent=//first html page as string content

      mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8","" );

      // some code

      webContent=//second html string  as string content 
      mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/",webContent, "text/html", "UTF-8","" );`

but im getting
 03-31 13:26:45.448: INFO/System.out(462): java.lang.NullPointerException
any soln?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base url (first parameter to loadDataWithBaseURL()) should not be empty.

Comment: @vnshetty, can you display your `webContent` data?

Comment: its a html page nothing else.. First time it displays the html page properly after that im going to scroll up to 1400 pixel value and then im going to display antoher page....here im getting that error in logcat.

Comment: are there any relative paths (for exampke, to images) in the html page?